# How to return from function lvalue or rvalue based on parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue

Consider example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

auto get_r_value() { return std::string("hello"); }

int VAL = 15;
int& get_l_value() { return VAL;}

template<typename ...Types> auto&& func(Types... vars) {
    if constexpr (sizeof ... (vars) <= 2) {
        return get_l_value();
    } else {
        return get_r_value();  // warning: returning reference to temporary 
    }
}

int main() {

    auto&& a = get_l_value();
    a = 20;
    std::cout << VAL << std::endl; // print 20
    
    auto&& b = get_r_value();   // auto&& works as expected!
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    func(1, 2) = 30;  
    std::cout << VAL << std::endl;  // print 30

    std::cout << func(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;  // SEGMENTATION FAULT!
    
    return 0;
}
```

We can see that the `auto&&` type not works when it a return type!

Is there any way to return from function *lvalue* or *rvalue* based on template parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
template<typename ...Types> decltype(auto) func(Types... vars) {
    if constexpr (sizeof ... (vars) <= 2) {
        return get_l_value();
    } else {
        return get_r_value();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea6a523ccb53d4ac)